# Properly match nested brackets with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, wikitext

I'm attempting to parse a Wikipedia file dump with RegEx.

I want to match and remove everything between a set of brackets, including the brackets themselves. I also want to be able to check if the first word after the opening bracket is a certain word, and do not delete it if it is. In my case, a single bracket consists of two characters, say `{{` and `}}`.

For example, take the following sequence into consideration:

`{{{{}}{{}}{{}}}} Don't delete me {{notmeeither}}`

Using the following regex:

```
{{(?!(notmeeither))(.|\n)*?\}}
```

results in matching the first `{{{{}}`, resulting in leftover brackets. Making the match greedy does not help, as it affects the text in between as well as the text not supposed to be matched. How would I go about this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses

Comment: Hi! My question consists of two parts, firstly on how not to delete the part inbetween two brackets, and how to exclude a bracket if it matches a phrase after, neither of which is really answered by that.

Comment: Parsing wikitext with regex is not a good thing to do. [Wikitext is really hard to parse](https://github.com/spencermountain/wtf_wikipedia#readme) and regex is barely enough. Since wikitext also supports some (but not all) HTML syntax, here's the obligatory link: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). There are existing parsers that already did the heavy-lifting though: *[mwparserfromhell](https://pypi.org/project/mwparserfromhell)*, *[wikitextparser](https://pypi.org/project/wikitextparser)*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) package you can specify [recursive patterns](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html):

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.sub(r"{{(?!(notmeeither))((?>[^{}]+|(?R))*)}}","","{{{{}}{{}}{{}}}} Don't delete me {{notmeeither}}")
" Don't delete me {{notmeeither}}"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! Seeing the negated set, would it be possible should the brackets be two characters instead of one, like {{ and }}? Would it match other variations like {< and >}?

Comment: Sure, just try it: `regex.sub(r"{<(?!(notmeeither))((?>[^{<>}]+|(?R))*)>}","","{<{<>}{<>}>} Don't delete me {<notmeeither>}")`

Comment: Hi so sorry, this works perfectly! I just have one more question: is there a way to match and verify if there is a "|" somewhere in the brackets? This is what i have so far: `{{(?!(Main))((?>[^{{}}]+|(?R))*)(.|\n)*?(?!}})\|+(.|\n)*?}}` It seems to have some issue with overmatching.

Comment: Sure, here it is: `{{(?!(main))((?>[^{}|]|{{(?2)}})*)\|((?>[^{}]|{{(?3)}})*)}}`. Take a look at [here](https://regex101.com/r/6swOex/1) for a demo.

Comment: P.S. Beware you don't need double brackets in `[^{}]` since `[...]` denotes a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: So sorry, I seem to have run into another wall. It should seem that inverting the negative lookahead would allow me to delete only brackets with the first word starting with `main`, but this does not seem to be the case! May I ask why, and how would I go about doing this? Thank you so much!

Comment: The original regex won't work because it recurses on the whole pattern, so also the inner templates {{...}} should start with "main". The last regex that I provided you [actually works](https://regex101.com/r/QH0MjZ/1). If you want to remove the at-least-one-"|" constraint, then use `{{(?=here)((?>[^{}]|{{(?1)}})*)}}` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/F1UOlH/1)).

Comment: For the next time(s), please be more accurate when you write the original question.